# How do I avoid duplication in graph from scanner? Java implementation

Tags: java, arraylist

I want it to register integers with no duplicates but it seems to be a lot harder than single digits. My input is 1 0; 1 as the source and 0 as the destination. If 1 0 is already present in the list and user inputs 1 0 or 0 1 the loop should identify it as duplicate thus ignoring it and continues with the loop without adding increment.

The problem is I can't seem to avoid having duplicates including interchangeable endpoints. It keeps registering.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.print("Enter the number of vertices: "); 
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in); 
        int num = s.nextInt();
        
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >();
        
        int n1 = num-1; int n2 = num*n1; int n3 = n2/2;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            adj.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());    
        }
        
        int count = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter edge: "); 
        for(int i = 1; i <= n3; i++){ 
            int src = s.nextInt();
            int dest = s.nextInt();
            if (src == dest) { 
                System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
                i--;
                continue;
            } else {
                if (adj.contains(src)){
                    if (adj.contains(dest)){
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
                        i--;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        try {
                            addEdge(adj, src, dest); 
                            count++;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
                            i--;
                            continue;
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
static void addEdge(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > Adj, int a, int b){ 
        Adj.get(a).add(b);
        Adj.get(b).add(a);
    }
```

Comment: This `if (adj.contains(src)){` will never be true, and therefore the code inside that `if` statement will never be run because `adj` is of type `ArrayList<Integer>`, but `src` is of type `int` which is not an `ArrayList`. This also applies to `if (adj.contains(dest)){`

Comment: @sorifiend Thanks for pointing that. I can't think of any solutions at the moment. I tried converting it to hashset but then again it didn't work. My knowledge of this language isn't that wide.